# Why my laravel 8 app does not show mix success/error notifications on fresh Kubuntu 20?

Tags: ubuntu, laravel-mix

Moving to kubuntu 20 from kubuntu 18
my laravel 8 I work now does not show mix success/error notification at right bottom corner

In webpack.mix.js of my project(I did not modify it):
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
        require('postcss-import'),
        require('tailwindcss'),
    ]);
```

Is it some OS misconfire? How can I fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decision is to add libnotify-bin package into my OS